# How to configure submit button in php forms such that only one data is posted at a time?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a php form where data in each row can be submitted independently. I am able to create a form which looks similar to the image below.
[image]

How to configure the submit buttons such that when pressed, the entry in that particular row alone gets posted to the server.
I am very new to PHP

Relevant php code:

```
while ($driverEntries = mysqli_fetch_row($driverList)) {
        printf ("%s \n",  $driverEntries[1]);
        echo "<input name=\"subject\" type=\"text\" id=\"subject\" size=\"50\">";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
        echo "<br>";
 }
```

Comment: Search for AJAX + PHP.

Comment: you'll probably want a separate form for each line too...

Comment: I know a little bit of ajax, but still dont know the exact commands to configure submit button

Comment: as @Dan said, create a specific form for each rows.

Comment: Here is a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890533/send-single-input-with-ajax-jquery-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$a=0;
while ($driverEntries = mysqli_fetch_row($driverList)) {
    printf ("%s \n",  $driverEntries[1]);
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\some_page.php\">";
    echo "<input name=\"subject\" type=\"text\" id=\"subject_$a\" size=\"50\">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</form>";
    $a++;
}
```

One form for each input.
Note the `$a` autoincrement to make the id diferent

**Ajax version(Using JQUERY)**

```
$a=0;
while ($driverEntries = mysqli_fetch_row($driverList)) {
    printf ("%s \n",  $driverEntries[1]);
    echo "<input name=\"subject\" type=\"text\" id=\"subject_$a\" size=\"50\">";
    echo "<span onclick=\"update($a)\">Update</span>";
    echo "<br>";
    $a++;
} 

<script>
 function update(a){
   subject=$('#subject_'+a).val();
    $.post('your_form_page_processor.php', 
    {subject:subject}, 
    function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
 }
</script>
```

In your_form_page_processor.php

```
$subject=isset($_POST['subject'])?$_POST['subject']:NULL;

if(!empty($subject)){
//do something with $subject
}else{
echo 'Subject cannot be empty'; 
}
```

Depend of what you want to do

You should read about [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and their [helper functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/helper-functions/)

Comment: Won't this result in navigating away from the page when you submit one of the form? If you have entered data in the other two fields, you lose this data?

Comment: what will some_page.php contain ? When i press submit button wont my current page will go away ?

Comment: some_page.php contain the code to preccess your form...that depend of what you want to do do with those data

Comment: if you want state in the same page and keep the other input data you could use ajax

Comment: what is `subject:subject` in script part

Comment: `subject:subject` is `parameter name:$('#subject_'+a).val()`

Comment: In this case when does the actual update takes place? After I finish typing and press return?

Comment: Also I after pressing return I dont want to loose focus from the current field. I thought when I am using AJAX shouldn't that be happening automatically?

Comment: for put focus you can use `$('#input').focus();` inside a callback function `function(result){//add $('#your_input').focus();}`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
while ($driverEntries = mysqli_fetch_row($driverList)) {
        printf ("%s \n",  $driverEntries[1]);
        echo "<form method='post'>";
        echo "<input name=\"subject\" type=\"text\" id=\"subject\" size=\"50\">";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<br>";
 }
```

But don't forget to remove main form because now we used different forms for each row.

Comment: he can simply use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: How do I specify which file should run when this data is posted ?

Comment: You use the `action` attribute to specify where the form should be submitted to, just like any other form.

Answer (score 0):

you can put each input into its own form, or you could use AJAX requests

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to separate each line input out into a separate form and then use AJAX to send and receive information from the php forms in page. Here's a good tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp Hope that helps!

Comment: If you use AJAX, you don't need to put each line into a separate form. You don't need any form at all, in fact.